# React Too many re-renders Drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a button with onClick -> pop Drawer from bottom. This is the code I use:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {
  const [actionBarOpen, setActionBarOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const closeActionBar = () => {
    setActionBarOpen(false);
  };

  const list = (
    <Box
      role="presentation"
      onClick={setActionBarOpen(false)}
      onKeyDown={setActionBarOpen(false)}
    >
      <List>
        {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <React.Fragment key={"bottom"}>
        <Button onClick={setActionBarOpen(true)}>Click me</Button>
        <Drawer anchor={"bottom"} open={actionBarOpen} onClose={closeActionBar}>
          {list}
        </Drawer>
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the page is not rendered and the message:
`Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`
is shown

[here is the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-waterfall-y4yd7g?file=/Demo.js)

Comment: You're calling `setActionBarOpen` on every render rather passing a function reference to `onClick`. Change it to `onClick={() => setActionBarOpen(true)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the too many re-renders error has to do with how you are using the `onClick` event handler on the `Button`. You are invoking `setActionBarOpen(true)` function immediately when rendering the component, leading to excessive re-renders. You need to pass a function as your event handler instead. See below;

```
<Button onClick={() => setActionBarOpen(true)}>Click me</Button>
```

Hope this helps.